Estimating a solution $u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^3)$ of the incompressible Euler equation in terms of $|\nabla u|_{L^{\infty}}$
Now let $u$ be a solution to:
\begin{equation}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
    & \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + (u \cdot \nabla)u + \nabla p = 0  \\
    & \nabla \cdot u = 0 \\
    & u_0 \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^3), u_{0} \leq N_{0}, s \geq 3
    \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
We want to prove the following estimate of $u$. Every norm is being taken over the whole space.
\begin{equation*}
|u(t)|_{H^s} \leq |u(0)|_{H^s} \exp\left(C\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} |\nabla u(\tau)|_{L^\infty} \, d\tau \right)
\end{equation*}
Now this estimate is heuristically derived in a Paper of Bealo, Kato and Majda(https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf01212349) As follows: $\alpha$ being a multiindice with $|\alpha| \leq s$
\begin{align*}
     D_{x}^\alpha u = v \text{,} \,
     D_{x}^\alpha (\nabla p) = \nabla q
\end{align*}
and adding a zero to get
\begin{equation*}
 v_{t} + (u \cdot \nabla) v +q = -F
\end{equation*}
Where we definend
\begin{equation}
   F = D^\alpha (u \cdot \nabla  u) - u \cdot \nabla D^\alpha u
\end{equation}
Note here, that $(u \cdot \nabla) v$ and $F$, do not exist for our given $u$. Now assuming higher regularity we can also use the following inequality:
\begin{equation*}
\|D^{\alpha}((u \cdot \nabla)u) - uD^{\alpha}\nabla u \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N}) \leq C_{s}(|Du|_{L^{\infty}} \|D^{s-1} \nabla u\|_{L^2} + |\nabla u|_{L^{\infty}} \|D^{s}u\|_{L^2})
\end{equation*}
Therefore multiplying by $v$ on both sites of our differential equation for $v$ and integrating over the whole space gives us the following differential inequality
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \displaystyle\frac{d}{dt} |v|_{0}^2 \leq C |\nabla u|_{L^\infty} |u|_{H^s} |v|_{L^2}
\end{equation*}
From now on our desired inequality follows from summing on both sites over $0 \leq \alpha \leq s$ and using the differential Gronwall Inequality. This is easy, so the hard part is to arrive at the first inequality, without neglecting the regularity of $u$.
Now the Authors give us the very brief explanation on how this could be reasoned:
„The heuristic approach can be justified by regarding $v$ as the weak solution of a linear equation(the equation above) in the class $C([0,T];L^2)$(T being the assumed time of existence of $u$) and arguing for linear hyperbolic equations. (We approximate $v(0)$ by smooth initial data, derive an $L^2$ energy estimate, and pass to the limit, using the uniqueness of weak solutions.)“
Now with this explanation I can‘t get anywhere mainly because i do not know how we argue for linear hyperbolic equations.
I also discussed this with my Professor and he said the following Ansatz should be right. Here $\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}$ is the mollification. Meaning:
\begin{equation*}
  (\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}u)(x) := \int \epsilon^{-3}\rho(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}) u(y) \, dy
\end{equation*}
With $\rho \in C_{c}^{\infty}(B_{1}(0))$ and $\int \rho = 1$
\begin{align*}
        &\quad \quad \quad u_{t} + (u\cdot \nabla)u + \nabla p = 0 \\
        &\iff D_{x}^{\alpha} \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}\big( u_{t} + (u\cdot \nabla)u + \nabla p\big) = 0 \\
        &\iff \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}v_{t} + D_{x}^{\alpha} \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}\big((u \cdot \nabla)u\big) + D_{x}^{\alpha} \nabla \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}p = 0 \\
        &\iff \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}v_{t} + (u\cdot \nabla)D_{x}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}u + D_{x}^{\alpha} \nabla \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}p = (u\cdot \nabla)D_{x}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}u - D_{x}^{\alpha} \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}\big((u \cdot \nabla)u\big)
\end{align*}
From here on multiplying with $\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}v$ on both sites an integrating over the whole space already gives the right expression on the left side with $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Another thing that is fairly obvious is that with adding a zero on the right side we can make use of the inequality that is being used in our heuristic approach:
\begin{align*}
 &\quad \int \Big[(u\cdot \nabla)D_{x}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}u - D_{x}^{\alpha}\big((u \cdot \nabla)(\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}u)\big) \big] \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}v \, dy \\
&+ \int \Big[D_{x}^{\alpha}\big((u \cdot \nabla)(\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}u)\big) - D_{x}^{\alpha} \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}\big((u \cdot \nabla)u\big)\Big] \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}v \, dy
\end{align*}
Using some properties of mollifiers and our inequality in the heuristic approach the first integral can be estimated to our desired factors $C|\nabla u|_{L^\infty} |u|_{H^s} |v|_{L^2}$
But from this point on im stuck. The second integral should either be have the same estimated or being 0. My Professor suggested the following approach. Writing $D_{x}^{\alpha-1}D_{x} := D_{x}^{\alpha}$ and using the Product rule on the second integral to get:
\begin{align*}
&\quad \int D_{x}^{\alpha-1} \Big[\big((D_{x}u \cdot \nabla)(\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}u)\big) - \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}\big((D_{x}u \cdot \nabla)u\big)\Big] \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}v \, dy \\
&+ \int D_{x}^{\alpha-1} \Big[\big((u \cdot \nabla)(\mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}D_{x}u)\big) - \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}\big((u \cdot \nabla)D_{x}u\big)\Big] \mathbf{T}_{\epsilon}v \, 
\end{align*}
He says the the first part can simply be estimated with the product rule and the second part with the commutator estimate. But i can‘t get anywhere with this Ansatz.
So i really have no idea how to proof this or should i say all my ideas failed to proof this. I really hope somebody can help me or tell me if there is any written down proof for this. I will be glad for any suggestions, since this is the last thing on my Bachelor thesis and i simply can‘t get it done…:(
Everything above should be important for solving this Problem, but if wanted i can also share the things i have learned about this, where i am not sure if they things are important.
